# Why is "C/C++:" being inserted into the label of my tasks.json file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, json, debugging, visual-studio-code, task

I am using Visual Studio Code with MinGW-w64. This involves creating two files (launch.json and tasks.json) that allow me to build and debug my C++ code. I select my tasks.json file by going to Terminal --> Configure Default Build Task... and then selecting "C/C++: g++.exe build active file."

Normally, the tasks.json file appears as follows:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, in the last few days, it has appeared as follows:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

When the file is in this format, I'm not able to debug my code. Instead, I get the message "Could not find the task 'g++.exe build active file'.

The only apparent difference is that `C/C++`is now preceding `g++.exe build active file` in the `"label"` line. Once I delete this label, I'm able to get the code to compile and/or debug.

This leads me to ask two questions: first, why is `C/C++` being inserted in the label? It doesn't appear in the Microsoft documentation for setting up MinGW with Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Secondly, how am I able to permanently remove `C/C++` from my label so that I don't have to manually delete it each time? I have tried choosing Configure Task next to C/C++:g++.exe build active file in the Configure Default Build Tasks in the dropdown menu; removing `C/C++`, and then saving the tasks.json file, but this doesn't appear to cause the build task to change permanently.

Thank you as always for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to read the source code of the cpptools extension, and then I found some problems. Under different conditions, the extension has different response

If there is ".vscode" folder in the folder root directory, then when adding the debug configuration, it will only guide the creation of launch.json.The user needs to be guided to configure "tasks.json" again.But the name of the task created at this time is not consistent with value of "preLaunchTask". This is a problem with this extension. I think the reason is that the ".vscode" folder was not found when initializing the debug configuration, some conditions are missing when the extension's code is executed

If there is a empty ".vscode" folder in the root directory of the folder, "launch.json" and "tasks.json" will be created at the same time when initializing the debug configuration.The two files are exactly matched and do not need any modification

If the user configures the task as first.When initializing the debug configuration, the extension will recreate a task called "g++.exe build active file" which is not start with "C/C++".This of course works, but you may need to delete the task created at the beginning whichhas not been used
This design is reasonable because "C/C++: g++.exe build active file" is actually a task template built into cpptools (there are two others). The built-in templates can be referenced by "preLaunchTask", but the user cannot see them in "tasks.json"
If you delete the file "tasks.json" and change the value of "preLaunchTask" to "C:C++: g++.exe build active file".It also works,but this is not a standard usage

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a mistake of them, it started to appear after a recent version

Comment: I hope it will be corrected soon then. Is there any way that I can correct the template myself, or will I need to continue to make a manual change to each instance of the form?